# how to put and retrieve laravel collection object on Session

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I know that we can insert array in Session as `Session::push('person.name','torres')` but how to keep laravel collection object such as `$product = Product::all();`,as like `Session::put('product',$product);`.Ho wto achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can put any data inside the session, including objects. Seeing as a `Collection` is just an object, you can do the same.

For example:

```
$products = Product::all();
Session::put('products', $products);
dd(Session::get('products'));
```

Should echo out the collection.

Comment: What's the syntax to access single properties from the object?

Answer (score 5):

You should convert it to a plain array, then convert them back to models:

### Storing in the session

```php
$products = Product::all()->map(function ($product) {
    return $product->getAttributes();
})->all();

Session::put('products', $products);
```

### Retrieving from the session

```php
$products = Product::hydrate(Session::get('products'));
```

---

You can see an example of this method [here](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/blob/183d29c5b46f02c00ec51783589d6fa86a6c2c64/src/CachedClipboard.php#L142-L164).

Comment: Why should I convert it to a plain array?

Comment: `Session::put('products', $products->toArray());` worked for me too.

I used `Address::newModelInstance(Session::get('address'));` to get a single instance.